# Get a list of each value in a column and how many times it occurs sorted from highest to lowest

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following database

```
person_id| field a | field b |friend_id
```

Lets suppose friend_id is the id of a person which the given person likes and it's optional the default case corresponding to 0;

I want to sort the persons in order of their popularity in the group i.e. in the order of the number of times the person's id has been listed as the friend_id.

What would the query be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What group?

From what I read, you want to see the most popular friend_ID by "GROUP"
but i'm not sure what group you mean.

So this gives you the most popular "Friend_ID" across the entire table.

```
Select count(Friend_ID), Friend_ID
from table
Group by friend_ID
Order by count(friend_ID) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      YT1.Person_ID,
      YT1.FieldA,
      YT1.FieldB,
      PreQuery.Popularity
   from
      YourTable YT1
         JOIN ( select YT.friend_id, 
                       count(*) as Popularity
                    from YourTable YT
                    group by YT.friend_id ) PreQuery
            on YT1.Person_ID = PreQuery.Friend_ID
   order by 
      PreQuery.Popularity DESC
```